# Is there a cleaner way to toggle class for form validation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

[image]

I am implementing the above view. The table is created through an AJAX call. To create the red validation boxes, I create the table as such:

```
for($r = 0; $r < sizeof($dataArray); $r++)
  for($i = 2; $i < $fields; $i++){      
    if(fieldIsValid($dataArray[$r][$i], $dataArray[$r][2], $i)){
        Echo "<td><input class='stageAreaInput' onchange='updateData(this.value, ".$r.", ".$i.")' value='".$dataArray[$r][$i]."'></td>";
    } else{         
        Echo "<td><input class='stageAreaInput invalidInput' onchange='updateData(this.value, ".$r.", ".$i.")' value='".$dataArray[$r][$i]."'></td>";
    }
  }
}
```

The `invalidInput` class is what triggers the red box. But now, I need to break out several rows to identify them individually for autocomplete. I feel that a long series of if statements is inefficient.

**Is there a better way to toggle the `invalidInput` class if I must now `Echo` each line individually?**

Let me know if more of my code would be helpful.

Comment: i would go with a function that returns the `invalidInput` called in the loop

Comment: I'm gonna try that approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you tagged this question with `jquery`. You can use the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method to add and remove a class automatically whenever it's called.

**jQuery**

```
$(".stageAreaInput").toggleClass("invalidInput");
```

*OR*

If you want to do it inline with your `PHP` loop you can use a [ternary statement](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) to toggle the class. It will shorten up your code, but (arguably) make it less human readable.

**Inline PHP: Ternary**

```
for($r = 0; $r < sizeof($dataArray); $r++){
    for($i = 2; $i < $fields; $i++){       
        echo "<td><input class='stageAreaInput ".((fieldIsValid($dataArray[$r][$i], $dataArray[$r][2], $i)) ? "" : "invalidInput")."' onchange='updateData(this.value, ".$r.", ".$i.")' value='".$dataArray[$r][$i]."'></td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can an if statement trigger that as I build the table?

Comment: After you are done building the table, you can call this to set the invalid fields to invalid. I'll add another way to do it in `PHP` as it looks like that's what you're asking here.

Comment: Very elegant! perfect solution